# getting a word after a defined keyword like "name Prasaanth"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

how can i get the date using ruby / nokogiri from this:

```
<p class="class1">
                    Expires 15/07/2011. that is my graduation day.</p><p>something else here</p>
```

my intension is to het the date.i read the forum which suggests me to use something like:

```
exp = node.at('[text()="Expires"]').next.text 
return exp
```

but its not working,please help.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
exp = node.at('[text()="Expires"]')
```

won't work because it is looking for text nodes that are exactly `"Expires"` and you're looking for text nodes that match `/^\s*Expires/`. You could probably find your `<p>` with a pile of nasty [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) or you could find the paragraphs and do the searching in Ruby:

```
doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
node = doc.search('p').find { |n| n.content[/^\s*Expires/] }
return nil if(!node)
exp = node.content.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
return exp ? exp[0] : nil
```